# cumprod on xts object - skip rows with value = 0

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts object of a stock. Now I have added the daily returns with the `quantmod::dailyReturn()` function. I now want to add a cumulative product column but as some return days for my data set will be 0, the cumulative product must skip these rows, how can this be achieved efficiently?

I would preferably not want to slice the data or filter it.

My data

```
            dailyChange    Return
2009-06-02 -0.027295285 -0.027295285
2009-06-03 -0.012755102 -0.012755102
2009-06-04  0.012919897  0.012919897
2009-06-05  0.022959184  0.022959184
2009-06-08 -0.007481297 -0.007481297
2009-06-09  0.027638191  0.027638191
2009-06-10  0.012224939  0.012224939
2009-06-11  0.043478261  0.043478261
2009-06-12  0.011574074  0.011574074
2009-06-15 -0.048054920 -0.048054920
2009-06-16 -0.012019231 -0.012019231
2009-06-17 -0.036496350 -0.036496350
2009-06-18  0.010101010  0.010101010
2009-06-19  0.000000000  0.000000000
2009-06-22 -0.055000000  0.000000000
2009-06-23  0.031746032  0.000000000
2009-06-24  0.046153846  0.046153846
2009-06-25  0.009803922  0.009803922
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
xt1$CumProd <-0
xt1$CumProd[xt1[,2]!=0] <- cumprod(xt1[,2][xt1[,2]!=0])
```